# Cache shows old updated pictures in my VUE JS Application

Tags: caching, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a problem that had me really ansious. I have a vue application where I have users profile, users timeline etc...

To make the short history, the problem is that:

In my user profile I have 4 pictures that I can upload or delete. So, when I update my pictures, sometimes the browser shows the old ones,but, when I do: CTRL+SHIFT+R the browser shows the new ones.

It seems a problem that can be fixed with location.reload(true) but it does not work for me. This is the flow:

1-Select picture
2-Send form to node server
3-In node server I upload the pictures and send the answer if everything its ok
4-dispatch vuex to get my data again and save it in the state
5-console.log the new state (it shows the new items updated)
6-location.reload(true)
7-here, where I should see my new images, it shows the old ones, however the state is updated. But, when i reload the page, it shows the new ones.

When I validate the form is ok I do the follow to dispatch edit and get the new data>

```
        const response = await this.$store.dispatch('company/edit', this.formData)
        if (response.success === true) {
            await this.$store.dispatch('company/populate', this.currentUser.identifier)
         }
```

First I dispatch the edit as follow>

```
        async edit ({commit, rootGetters}, form) {
      commit('setStatus', { loading: true, error: false, message: '' })
      const endpoint = form.get('editing') === 'solutions' ? '/api/solution/register' : '/api/company/edit/' + form.get('editing')
      const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + rootGetters['auth/getToken'] }

      try {
        await axios.post(endpoint, form, { headers: headers })
        commit('setStatus', { loading: false, error: false, message: 'Success' })
        return { success: true }
      } catch (error) {
        let message = ''
        if (error.response) {
          message = error.response.data.message
        } else if (error.request) {
          message = 'No response received from the server. If the problem persists contact the site administrator (' + error.message + ')'
        } else {
          message = error.message
        }
        commit('setStatus', { loading: false, error: true, message: message })
        return { success: false }
      }
    },
```

Then if it is succcess>

```
        const endpoint = '/api/company/' + identifier
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + rootGetters['auth/getToken'] }

        try {
          const {data} = await axios.get(endpoint, { headers: headers })
          // await commit('clear')
          await commit('setData', data.company)
          console.log('DATA COMPANY', data.company)
          if (silent === false) {
            commit('setStatus', { loading: false, error: false, message: 'Success' })
          }
          return { success: true }
        } catch (error) {
          ......
```

And this are my mutations and state>

```
        const state = {
      data: null,
      status: {
        loading: false,
        silent: false,
        error: false,
        message: ''
      }
    }

    const mutations = {
      setData (state, data) {
        data.solutions = data.solutions === null ? [] : data.solutions
        Vue.set(state, 'data', data)
        return {success: true}
      },

      setStatus (state, status) {
        Vue.set(state, 'status', status)
      },

      clear (state) {
        state.data = null
        return {success: true}
      }
    }
```

I have checked the database after I updated my pictures, and it updated, so its not a backend problem.

I dont know what to do, i have read a lot but i can not get to the solution. And the problems appears in some browsers and others dont

Thanks for reading

Comment: Just add the code the way your state object is updated.Most probably you are not updating it following vue's reactivity principles.

Comment: @Riddhi thanks, I have updated the question with the code. Thanks for your time, can you check

Comment: Try declaring data as empty object. data: null =>data:{}.

Answer (score 3):

You can force to get new images by changing url, adding some query parameters for example, version or timestamp depend on what you have available.

```
<img src="profile.gif" >
```

When user updates:

```
<img src="profile.gif?version=1">
```